# Panel Data_ Data varies with Time not Accross

Tags: panel-data, dataset

I am working on supply response of major crops in Pakistan for my thesis. I have zone wise data for prices, area and production. Each zone has a few Districts in it. Now all the area and production data varies but the prices are same for all the districts ( all district farmers sell in the same central zonal market). Will that cause any violation of conditions for panel data analysis.

Comment: what is the objective of your study. which technique you intend to apply. panel data analysis ?

Comment: Using ARDL for Supply Response